# How to play mp3 from bytes?

Tags: python, pygame, mp3, pyaudio

Is there a way to play mp3 from bytes directly using python? If not, can I convert the binary to a different audio format and make the binary playable?

Edit: The following code works for `wav` files but not `mp3`

```
from pygame import mixer, time

mixer.pre_init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)
mixer.init()

data = open('filename.mp3', 'rb').read()
sound = mixer.Sound(buffer=data)

audio = sound.play()
while audio.get_busy():
    time.Clock().tick(10)
```

Edit:
The problem has been solved, see my answer below if you're facing a similar issue

Comment: Just to clarify, you have a file in .mp3 format and you want to play it using Python?  And what operating system are you using?

Comment: I don't, I'm streaming mp3 binary and I don't want to write it to disk. I'm using mac but a solution for linux is also fine.

Comment: Just to clarify when you say binary, is it an array of amplitudes, or is it actually in mp3 format?  And when you say streaming, do you mean it has to be done in real-time?

Comment: Not sure how to do this in real-time, but if you find that you can write short snippets to disk, maybe you could use `os.system("afplay path/temp.mp3")`.  Might need more detail to get a more helpful answer.

Comment: Yes, it's done in real time and I want to play audio after receiving a few thousand bytes. Sorry, I shouldn't be using the word binary. It's actual mp3 formatted bytes.

Comment: I'm using afplay and tempfiles currently but I want to do it without having to save to disk like I mentioned.

Comment: You might be able to put the data in a `StringIO` or `BytesIO` instance and pass that to whatever plays mp3s like it was a file.

Comment: That's what I want to find

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For anyone who might be facing a similar problem, this works

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
from pydub.playback import play
import io

data = open('filename.mp3', 'rb').read()

song = AudioSegment.from_file(io.BytesIO(data), format="mp3")
play(song)
```

Comment: Thanks for this option , I was struggling to get IPython Audio working

Comment: tried this, but getting an ffmpeg error, my question is did you have ffmpeg installed via pip or into your OS?

Answer (score 3):

I saw your pygame tag, so I'll to do this in pygame. Pygame can load files from bytes with this line: `sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(bytes)` or `sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(buffer=bytes)`. I can't guarantee this will work with mp3 files, though, you may need to use OGG or WAV files, as bytes.

Comment: I've added a code snippet in my post. This works for `wav` but `mp3` files sound corrupted.